# How do you play a list of audio files in order with Alexa?

Tags: audio, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building an Alexa app built on a rails backend right now. So far I can pretty easily play an audio file by returning this JSON on a LaunchRequest:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "PlainText",
                "text": "Welcome To My App"
            },
            "directives": [
                {
                    "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
                    "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
                    "audioItem": {
                        "stream": {
                            "token": "12345",
                            "url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-s3-bucket/songs/audio_files/000/000/008/original/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3?1523318953", 
                            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "shouldEndSession": true
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine and plays the audio file located in my s3 bucket. What I can't even come close to figuring out is how to have a new audio file automatically play after the current one ends, or when I say "Alexa, next."

From what I've gathered, I need to use the "ENQUEUE" playBehavior, tokens and expectedPreviousTokens, and the PlaybackNearlyFinished. however, I can't find any good tutorials or code examples that explain how to use any of these things.

How is PlaybackNearlyFinished sent? Is it sent from my rails backend to Alexa or from Alexa to my rails backend? How do I respond to it? How do I respond to it in such a way that it adds a new audio file to the queue?

If anyone can explain how I would go about adding a new audio file to the queue please fill me in, or direct me to a tutorial that explains how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I can't even come close to figuring out is how to have a new audio file automatically play after the current one ends

You have to implement the Amazon Audio Player methods. These actions will be called automatically. For example if the playback comes to an end, the onPlaybackNearlyFinished() method gets invoked. So you have to implement your own logic within these methods in order to enqueue your next song. For the next song simply add a new PlayDirectiv as response to the onPlaybackNearlyFinished with PlayBehavior.ENQUEUE .

> , or when I say "Alexa, next."

This is a regular AMAZON.NextIntent you have to implement your own logic as well (for example send a random song as play directive with PlayBehavior.REPLACE_ALL)

> How is PlaybackNearlyFinished sent? Is it sent from my rails backend to Alexa or from Alexa to my rails backend? How do I respond to it? How do I respond to it in such a way that it adds a new audio file to the queue?

It is send from "Alexa to your rails backend" so you have to implement all AudioPlayer methods (in Java simply add "implements Speechlet, AudioPlayer" to your class). This will provide all necessary methods (for example the onPlaybackNearlyFinished method) and you can write your logic as described above.

Please note that you can only respond with a PlayDirective to the AudioPlayer Actions!! Any output speech or reprompt will cause problems!